# Google Sheets SQL Query

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I need your help in an SQL query in Google Sheets

I need a query to **Select columns that have** for example **A1** in their name

My problem is that i have more than 150 columns that contain A1 in their title so a query like
query(range,"select D E F where .....") is not helpful as i need to write by hand more than 150 columns!!

So i need a query that either selects columns with certain string in their name or a sggestion to add a specific range in select claus

Here is an example image
[image]

and the link of my sample form https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pYr1Rx0VasXjmAQC0qa9zNC_3rAdg_dxUKLy42zFTCY/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B3:M15), "where Col1 matches 'date|name|^A1.+'"))
```

[image]

Comment: Absolutely yes palyer0..thanks a lot...I'm studying your function now. Is there a way to add filtering in the result? For example showing A1 columns as you managed but only for dates 10/2/2021